# Use AWS CLI --query option to filter a 1-dimensional array

Tags: aws-cli

Is it possible to use the --query option of the AWS CLI (described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html#controlling-output-filter)) to filter a 1 dimensional array?  All the examples I can find on the AWS site work great for maps -- but I couldn't figure out the syntax for a simple array.

Consider the dynamodb list-tables command which has a string array in the output:

```
aws dynamodb list-tables
```

Sample Output:

```
{
    "TableNames": [
        "Questions", 
        "Answers",
        "Votes"
    ]
}
```

Let's say I want to figure out if TableNames contains "Answers".  Syntax I've tried that's invalid or doesn't work.

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --query 'TableNames[?==`Answers`]'
aws dynamodb list-tables --query 'TableNames[?.==`Answers`]'
aws dynamodb list-tables --query '[?TableNames[*]==`Answers`]'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To refer to the current element in an array, you can use the `@` character:

```
$ aws dynamodb list-tables  --query "TableNames[? @ == 'Answers' ]"
[
    "Answers"
]
```

If you just need a true/false answer of "does this table name exist in the list of tables" you can also use:

```
$ aws dynamodb list-tables  --query "contains(TableNames, 'Answers')"
true
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!  Also, "does this item exist" is exactly the question I was trying to answer with the --query option.

Comment: This helped me for one simple reason: the double quotes around the query and the single quotes around the filter value.  It just didn't work any other way.